# iPhone: image horizontal gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am trying to create sample gallery before filling real data.

```
    float xAxis = 0;
    float mostHeight = self.galleryView.bounds.size.height;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        //getImage from url
        UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: 
                            [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                             [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-M9k3fhlUwmE/TdYgxL97xMI/AAAAAAAAAY8/_r45zbAm1p0/s1600/CARTOON_Cat-full.jpg"]]];
        myImage = [[MyMath sharedMySingleton] imageWithImage:myImage convertToSize:CGSizeMake(mostHeight - 10, mostHeight - 10)];
        //set image
        UIImageView *rview= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        /*adding the view to your scrollview*/
        [self.galleryView addSubview:rview];
        xAxis += myImage.size.width + 20;
    }
    //set scrolling area
    self.galleryView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xAxis, mostHeight);
```

galleryView is UIScrollView from xib. Here, i am trying to fill 5 same pictures to gallery, but it fills only one and space after that (because of xAxis number). What did i do wrong?

P. S. I am new in iPhone sdk, so don't judge me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the frame for the `UIImageView`. You need to offset the `x` coordinate of the `origin` of the `frame` (`frame.origin.x`) by width of the image view + padding.

Comment: could you show me more about it how can i accomplish that. I am really noob in iPhone sdk. I know what you are trying to say, but don't know how to get that

Comment: Do you want the UIImageViews to have the same size as seen from UIScrollView, or do you want them to be of variable size, but height = height of UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to set the frame for your imageView to with the x-Offset of xAxis.